# Change value of a public class variable in gtest C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

ClassToMock.hpp

```
enum class Flavors {Vanilla, Strawberry};

class ClassToMock
{
    public:
        Flavors flavorName = Flavors::Vanilla;
        .....
}
```

ClassRunner.cpp

```
class Runner
{
    void main()
    {
        ....
        ClassToMock* classToMock = new ClassToMock();
        if (classToMock->flavorName == Flavors::Strawberry)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test that sets the value of class variable `flavorName` to  `Flavors::Strawberry` and test the `if()` branch.

If I were to mock functions its easy to mock (mark the function in `ClassToMock.hpp` as `virtual` and mock it). But since `flavorName` is not a function, I am not able to set the value of `flavorName` to `Strawberry` in the test code. The value of `flavorName` is always set to the default value i.e. `Vanilla` when I call the `main()` from the TestCode.cpp.

TestCode.cpp

```
TEST_F(...)
{
    Runner* runner = new Runner();

    EXPECT_NO_THROW(runner->main());
}
```

I have also tried to create a mock class,

```
class MockClassToMock : public ClassToMock
{
    public:
        Flavors flavorName = Flavors::Vanilla;
}
```

but still changes are not picked.

Comment: You need to use some form of dependency injection. This requires refactoring your code.

Comment: In your example, the code inside the `if` is unreachable, unless you change `flavorName` in the constructor. There is no need to test it and it should be removed.